# How to capture http post data from Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to access HTML form data POSTed through a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613798/is-it-possible-to-access-html-form-data-posted-through-a-webview)

I like to know how i can capture http post values from my Android webview. I load a webform from my assets folder in a webview when I submit this form I like to capture the post values.

Any ideas how to get this done?

Thanks

Comment: in shouldInterceptRequest, you may look into the page to get the values of the fields.

Comment: Found this great article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface